# How to get the ID of the last record inserted in SQLite with Delphi 10?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey

Delphi 10 with Firemonkey and SQLite: After running the code below I want to get the ID of the last record inserted into an SQLite table.  How do I get the last ID?

NOTE: The ID field of Table 1 is autoincrement.

```
var myQr: TFDQuery;
begin

   myQr := TFDQuery.Create(Self);

   with myQr do begin
      SQL.Add('Insert into table1 values (:_id, :_name, :_dthr)');
      Params.ParamByName('_id').ParamType := TParamType.ptInput;
      Params.ParamByName('_id').DataType  := TFieldType.ftInteger;
      Params.ParamByName('_id').Value     := null;

      ParamByName('_name').AsString       := 'name test';
      ParamByName('_dthr').AsDateTime     := Now;
      ExecSQL;
   end;

   // How to get last ID?  <<<<<<<<<<<<<=================

   myQr.DisposeOf;
```

Comment: You could run a separate query `select top 1 _id from table1 order by 1 desc` but I'd recommend to instead use a select statement, open the query, use append, then after posting, simply read the ID. Especially since from the time you insert this, to the time you run the second query, chances are another client may have inserted something else in that time, so transaction mode would have to be added. So long story short, don't `Exec` an `Insert` statement. Instead, `Open` a `Select` statement, and use `Append` and `Post`.

Comment: @JerryDodge, before posting my question I tried to use `append` but could not make it work using parameters. I understand that using the parameters makes the system more secure, for example against SQLInjection. With the use of `append` is it possible to continue using the `parameters` that I indicate in my SQL statement? How?

Comment: If I recall, using `Append` and passing values to each field internally uses parameters, or at least, by nature should prevent SQL injection. So in other words, there's no need to use parameters when using the `Append` method.

Comment: Pretty much like `Q.SQL.Text := 'select * from ThisTable'; Q.Open; Q.Append; Q.FieldByName('MyField').AsString := 'Some Value'; Q.Post; NewID := Q.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;` At least that's how I do it in ADO, but FireDac shouldn't be much different, if at all.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could query [**last_insert_rowid**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) if your **ID** column is declared as [**INTEGER PRIMARY KEY**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). In such case the column becomes alias for the **ROWID**. If that is your case, you can query it natively e.g. this way:

```pascal
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper;

function GetLastInsertRowID(Connection: TFDConnection): Int64;
begin
  Result := Int64((TObject(Connection.CliObj) as TSQLiteDatabase).LastInsertRowid);
end;
```

Or in common way by calling [**GetLastAutoGenValue**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.GetLastAutoGenValue) method:

```pascal
function GetLastInsertRowID(Connection: TFDConnection): Int64;
begin
  Result := Int64(Connection.GetLastAutoGenValue(''));
end;
```

Comment: It works fine! Question: This way will dataset read only the last record entered in the table or It'll read all records from the table to get to the last one? I'm asking, because if the table is large, the process will be slow.

Comment: The remark that @JerryDodge, about another user inserting a new record between one transaction and another, would give problem in this case?

Comment: None of that. It returns last recorded `ROWID` after successful `INSERT` for database connection. In fact it's implemented as single session property called `lastRowid`. You can even change that value manually.

Comment: No, that doesn't apply. It's per connection property. You could get incorrect value only if you inserted tuple using the same connection from another thread.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ZaynBarcktu:  Victoria's way is definitely the way to do this.

Comment: @ZaynBarcktu Indeed, my initial comment about running a separate query is where you have the risk of another entry. So the only way to accomplish it accurately using my first method would require transaction mode. This, however, looks like an excellent way to do it, and it seems to be designed for your exact purpose.